# Analogy of Binary subtraction to decimal subtraction

Tags: arithmetic, binary, hash-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do +, -, *, / with number in a base b?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20347/how-to-do-with-number-in-a-base-b)
>   [Subtraction of numbers with arbitrary bases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161658/subtraction-of-numbers-with-arbitrary-bases)

This is a very basic question. But I come from non computer science background and is having trouble understanding this .  Lets say I want to subtract two binary numbers (say 100 - 001 = 011). How do I go about doing this subtraction ? Please provide an analogy for a decimal subtraction

P.S: Actually I found out that the `HashMap` in Java  requires its bucket size to be a power of 2 and finds the bucketIndex by the following code and this works well if n is a power of 2 . h is the value of the key to be hashed and length is number of buckets in the `HashMap`

```
static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
    return h & (length-1);
}
```

So I am assuming that that n here is 4 . So lets say we do 4-1 =3 which is 011 in binary .I am getting confused with borrowing operation here for the 2's place and 4's place during the subtraction process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You go for that subtraction exactly as you would do for decimal, except that you need to borrow already for $2=$`10`. So for your example, you have

```
  100
- 001
      <- place for borrows
  ___
```

So you start in the rightmost column, where you have $0-1$. Since $0<1$, you have to borrow from the left, so you have `10-1` that is $2-1$ which is $1$. So after this step, you end up with

```
  100
- 001
   1
  ___
    1
```

Now to the second solumn. Again, including the borrow, you have to subtract $1$ from $0$, so you need to borrow again. Again, you'll get `10-1`$=2-1=1$:

```
  100
- 001
  11
  ___
   11
```

Finally, with the left column, you have $1-1$, which doesn't need a borrow and gives $0$. So you end up with

```
  100
- 001
  11
  ___
  011
```

Which evidently is the correct result.

However it may be easier to first only collect the borrows and then subtract them in a separate step (continuing until no borrows are left). Note that this could be done in decimal subtraction as well. With that algorithm you collect the borrows *below* the preliminary result, and then restart the subtraction algorithm. This is especially useful for problems like `100-011` where the borrow gets larger than $1$. Here's how that method works:

```
  100
- 011
  ___
       <- Preliminaty result
    0  <- Borrows (initialized with a rightmost 0)
```

First, subtract the right-most column. This needs a borrow, which this time is noted *below*.

```
  100
- 011
  ___
    1
   10
```

Now we get to the second column. With the previous algorithm, you'd have to subtract $`10`$=2$, which is of course possibile with borrow, but you need to think a little bit more (which is especially bad if you are a computer and thus quite stupid). With this second algorithm, you just ignre the borrow for the moment, and subtract the second column normally (which again gives a borrow).

```
  100
- 011
  ___
   11
  110
```

Finally you subtract the leftmost column, which works without a borrow:

```
  100
- 011
  ___
  111
  110
```

Now the borrows are not empty, therefore you have to subtract them. Fortunately you know how to do that:

```
  100
- 011
  ___
  111
- 110
  ___
  001
```

Voila, the correct result!

OK, so why is this algorithm better? Well, because you never get a borrow larger than $1$, and since computers are especially good with $0$ and $1$, this is better suited for them. Moreover, if you look at the preliminary results, you'll find that each bit is `1` exactly if the original bits are different; that operation is known as XOR and is a basic logic operation which can be easily implemented on computers. Also, it is easy to see that the borrow now occurs exactly when the bit of the first number is `0` and the bit of the second number is `1`. Which is also a combination of two basic logical operations, NOT and AND.

Also note that the XOR is also valid for *addition*, only the borrow has to be changed to a carry. A carry happens exactly if both bits are `1`. So basically the only difference between binary addition and binary subtraction is a NOT on the first number when calculating the borrow instead of the carry.

Comment: so in step 1 I am borrowing a 2 from the 2'splace of the upper number right ? Also "except that you need to borrow already for 2=10" . What does this mean ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And if you look closely, I've written $2$ in math mode, and `10` in code mode. What I mean is the number $2$, written in binary as `10`.